# Singular values of random uniform matrix

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices, singular-values

Suppose  $X \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times M}$ with elements sampled i.i.d. from $\mathcal{U}(-\sigma, \sigma)$.

I would like to find the marginal distribution of the unordered singular values of $X$.
The case for $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma)$ has been extensively studied, but i can't seem to find any work on the uniform distribution case.

Or equivalently the distribution of the eigenvalues of $X^TX$. The distribution of the $X^TX$ seems to follow some gaussian with mean zero and a small gaussian in the tail as observed in some simulations. This leads to the eigenvalues not being distributed as gaussian i.i.d.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I now have the same problem.

Comment: You might try using Theorem 1 from these notes https://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/386/ClassicalEnsembles.pdf

Comment: I went with the solution of the MaCarlo suggested. Since this was a requirement for a computational issue the small errors for N, M larger than 10 or so were no problem. As for as i sought, i did not find an exact result.

Answer (score 5):

Rescale $Y=(\sqrt{3}/\sigma)X$, so that the matrix elements of $Y$ have uniform distribution with zero mean and unit variance.

In the limit $N,M\rightarrow\infty$ at fixed $M/N=r\in(0,1]$ the $M$ eigenvalues $\lambda_n$ of $N^{-1}Y^{\rm T}Y$ have the Marcenko-Pastur distribution,
$$\rho(\lambda)=\frac{1}{2\pi \lambda r}\sqrt{(\lambda_+-\lambda)(\lambda-\lambda_-)},\;\;\lambda_-<\lambda<\lambda_+,\;\;\lambda_\pm=(1\pm\sqrt r)^2.$$
For a proof, see for example these [notes.](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~valko/courses/833/2009f/lec_6_7.pdf)

The plot below is a test for $M=10^3$, $N=10^4$: the histogram shows the eigenvalue distribution for a randomly generated matrix with uniformly i.i.d. matrix elements, the curve is the Marcenko-Pastur distribution, which as you can see agrees very nicely.
<sub>(No idea why the histogram in the OP is so different.)</sub>

[image]

---

The OP has asked in the comment for non-asymptotic results. I don't think there are exact closed-form expressions for any $N,M$, but the large-$N$,$M$ asymptotics is already reached quite accurately for moderately large values of $N,M$. In the plot below I show the case $M=10,N=20$, which is already quite close to the Marcenko-Pastur limit.

[image]

And even $M=5,N=10$ is not too bad...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I was incomplete in my question. I am aware of the MP distribution, but i am looking for a general pdf or marginal distribution and not the limiting case since the applications requires all sizes of matrices.

Comment: you are looking for an exact result for any $M,N$ ? that will not be forthcoming, I'm afraid; however, I'm pretty confident that the "large-$M,N$" limit is reached with good accuracy already for moderately large values of $M,N$, say upwards of 10 or so.

Comment: I have added two plots to illustrate this.

Comment: Thank you, it seems that i have some accuracy issues with my code. Thank you for the clarification.